# Webpack + React : reusable component is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, chunks

I'm trying to create a React component **DynamicCollection** which I want to use multiple times in the same page.

What I'd like is a file dynamicCollection.js from dynamicCollection.jsx and few files which use the component DynamicCollection like this :

- dyna1.js with `ReactDOM.render(<DynamicCollection p1=... p2=.../>,document.getElementById(dyna1));`
- dyna2.js with `ReactDOM.render(<DynamicCollection p1=... p2=.../>,document.getElementById(dyna2));`

...

In dynamicCollection.jsx I've got this :

```
export default class DynamicCollection extends React.Component { ... }
```

And finally in the webpack.config.js :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './app');

var config = {
    entry: {
        'DynamicCollection': './app/DynamicCollectionBox.jsx',
        'dyna1': './app/dyna1.js',
        'dyna2': './app/dyna1.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            loader : 'babel?presets[]=es2015'
        }
      ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

The problem is that I get this error in the browser console :

> ReferenceError: DynamicCollection is not defined

(Note : I included DynamicCollection.js, dyna1.js and dyna2.js in the html file)

Can you help please ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: the output filename will also be case sensitive. so u should include 'DynamicCollection.js' in html file.

Comment: Yes you're right. But even with this I've got the same message ...

Comment: @user2739974 and did you import component `DynamicCollection` from `DynamicCollection.jsx` in your files `dyna1.js` and `dyna2.js` and also you need not import these three files in your html rather only `[name].js` that is generated by your webpack

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri : yes I tried that with `import {DynamicCollection} from 'DynamicCollection.jsx'` but then I got a big file for dyna1.js.

Without the import, DynamicCollection.js size is 70 kB and dyna1.js and dyna2.js sizes are 2 kB but with the import dyna1.js and dyna2.js sizer are 71 kB so it's not very useful because the code of DynamicCollection is copied for every dynaX.js

Comment: well yeah it will be but see that what you use webpack for. when you want to use your code for production you use uglifyJs plugin with webpack and what it does it is that it removes all the redundant code and minified the file. So if that worked you must not worry about the file size because that is how you do it.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri : you're right. The best option for me would still be to have a component DynamicCollection which could use multiple times in the same page.

Comment: is `react` preset included in .babelrc or somewhere?

Comment: I included it in my html page and .babelrc

Comment: Would you provide one of your import statements?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the answer to this.
What I did was introduced the below attributes in webpack output;

```
library: 'ReactWelcomeComponent',
libraryTarget: 'var'
```

Then in my angular directive I am able to access the react component like below;

```
var JSXReactComponent = React.createFactory(ReactWelcomeComponent.default);
```

With this approach, I am able to call the React component that was generated as part of webpack step and access in angular context.